# Why the value of topological entropy of the identity map on a compact topological space is zero?

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I have tried to prove it using Adlar's definition of topological entropy. But I am little confused. Please help.

Comment: You mean "Adler"?  What do you know about topological entropy already? That is, what should an answer to your question be based on?

Comment: I have just started to study topological entropy. By Adlar's definition, I mean the definition of entropy using open covers in a compact topological space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the notation explained [by this exposition of Adler's work](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Topological_entropy#By_Adler.2C_Konheim_and_McAndrew), when $T$ is the identity map, $\mathcal{U}^n=\mathcal{U}$ and so $h(\mathcal U,T) = \lim\frac{N(\mathcal {U})}n=0$.  Or, by [this](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Topological_entropy#Basic_properties_of_topological_entropy), $h(T^n)=nh(T)$ for all $n\ge 1$; since $T^2=T$ we have $h(T)=2h(T)$ so $h(T)=0$.

Comment: Got the idea. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

The identity is an isometry. So it has topological entropy $0$.

Comment: Can you please show the proof applying the definition of topological entropy using open covers in a compact topological space?

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover, what can you say about $T^{-1} \mathcal{U}\vee \mathcal{U}$? What if you consider more iterates, how does the number of elements of that join change as you look at more iterates?

Comment: The number of elements in the join  does not changes as we go for more iterates. Thus the growth rate of number of elements in the join is zero and therefore the entropy is zero. Am I correct?